# Updating Word Mail Merge datasource before the merge using vba

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word, label, mailmerge

Here is my problem:

I have a `.csv` file that contains strings that represent bar codes. The bar codes  need to be printed out using Code 39 font in Word on Avery Label paper.

To accomplish this, I created a `.dotm` file. In the `.dotm` file, I created a Mail Merge using the `.csv` file as a data source. Everything works fine but the printed labels aren't legible by the bar code readers.

In order to correct this, I created a `VBA` macro on Document_Open of the `.dotm`file to add an * at the beginning and end of the bar code string. I want the macro to open the `.csv` file, read it, replace the bar code string with the appropriate string, and then write it back to the `.csv` before the mail merge occurs.

After opening the .dotm file, I get -

> Permission Denied.

If I run the VBA code from within VBA editor, it runs without any error. I'm not sure which location I would be getting the error from.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim oFSO, f, FilePath, ts, sLine, line, FileContent, sBar, sBarcode
Dim LineArray As Variant
Dim CodesArray() As String
Dim tFile As Integer
Dim tFile1 As Integer
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

FilePath = "\\mkaccup01\c$\AccutracXE\Barcode.csv"

tFile = FreeFile

'Open the datasource, read it, and modify it
Open FilePath For Input As tFile

FileContent = Input(LOF(tFile), tFile)

Close tFile

LineArray = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)
ReDim CodesArray(0 To 2) As String

For Each sLine In LineArray

    CodesArray = Split(sLine, ",")
    For Each line In CodesArray
        sBar = CodesArray(0)
        sBarcode = "*" & sBar & "*"
    Next

    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, sBar, sBarcode)
Next

'Open datasource back up and save the modifications
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = oFSO.GetFile(FilePath)
Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)

ts.Write FileContent
ts.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts.. 1) Normally, when you "use" a dotm file the event to work with is New_Document (or a macro named AutoNew). That's not the problem, but an important point for your project.

Comment: 2) You don't mention which line of code is triggering the error, is ti very early in the code? Likely, the document isn't open/ready when the code tries to run. Since this code isn't executing within Word there aren't any "safety checks" to make sure everything is "go" before Word lets it start. The typical way to get around this kind of thing is to discover a command in the Office application that isn't available until the document is completely loaded. Since VBA code is mostly synchronous (meaning the next line waits until the previous has executed) you might try changing the View to start.

Comment: Sorry. The error is happening at the "ts.Write FileContent" line of code. I think the problem is the macro is trying to update the contents of a data source that is currently being used by the active document's Mail Merge.

Comment: Interesting... Which version of Word are we dealing with? I take it the user is opening the document (not code)? If that's the case, then you can try first turning the document back to a "Normal" Word document (instead of MainMergeDocument), update the data source, then link it back in. In the object model: MainMergeDocument.Type and OpenDataSource

Comment: I'm using Word 2010.

Comment: Did my last suggestions help? Note that you can also save the document without the data source attached (change the MainMergeDocument.Type) - that won't delete any merge fields or anything, only unlink the data source. Then your current code should run with no problem if your surmise about the error is correct. Then just link up the data source and you should be good to go...

Comment: Let me get clear on your suggestion. You suggest to just create a blank Word document with no Mail Merge or macros. Then create a macro enabled doc that will make the changes to the data source, write the changes, open the blank doc, create the mail merge (using MainMergeDocument.Type) and set the mail merge data source (OpenDataSource). Is that along the lines you were suggesting?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Work with the document you have now. If you have control of this document, remove the data source from it (turn it into a "normal" Word document). Test whether your code runs - just to make sure the problem goes away when the document opens. If it does, AFTER the code you currently have, add ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource to link in the csv file. If you do NOT have control, your first line of code should change the document type to normal (release the data source), then the code you have now, then OpenDataSource to link back to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually took another route. I created a .dotm file, added the code to read & modify the data source, then added the coded to create the mail merge in a new document. That took care of my updating issue but now I need to change the font of the fields in the merge:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  ModifyDataSource
  CreateMerge
End Sub

Function CreateMerge()
Dim oApp As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document

'Start a new document in Word
Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add

With oDoc.MailMerge

    'Insert the mail merge fields temporarily so that
    'you can use the range that contains the merge fields as a layout
    'for your labels -- to use this as a layout, you can add it
    'as an AutoText entry.
    With .Fields
        .Add oApp.selection.Range, "barcode"
        oApp.selection.TypeParagraph
    End With
    Dim oAutoText As Word.AutoTextEntry
    Set oAutoText = oApp.NormalTemplate.AutoTextEntries.Add("MyLabelLayout", oDoc.Content)
    oDoc.Content.Delete 'Merge fields in document no longer needed now
                        'that the AutoText entry for the label layout
                        'has been added so delete it.

    'Set up the mail merge type as mailing labels and use
    'a tab-delimited text file as the data source.
    .MainDocumentType = wdMailingLabels
    .OpenDataSource Name:="\\mkaccup01\c$\AccutracXE\BARCODE.csv" 'Specify the data source here

    'Create the new document for the labels using the AutoText entry
    'you added -- 5160 is the label number to use for this sample.
    'You can specify the label number you want to use for the output
    'in the Name argument.
    oApp.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument Address:="", _
        AutoText:="MyLabelLayout", LaserTray:=wdPrinterManualFeed

    'Execute the mail merge to generate the labels.
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute

    'Delete the AutoText entry you added
    oAutoText.Delete

End With

'Close the original document and make Word visible so that
'the mail merge results are displayed
oDoc.Close False
oApp.Visible = True

'Prevent save to Normal template when user exits Word
oApp.NormalTemplate.Saved = True
End Function

Function ModifyDataSource()
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim oFSO, f, FilePath, ts, sLine, line, FileContent, sBar, sBarcode
Dim LineArray As Variant
Dim CodesArray() As String
Dim tFile As Integer
Dim tFile1 As Integer
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

FilePath = "\\mkaccup01\c$\AccutracXE\Barcode.csv"

tFile = FreeFile

'Open the datasource, read it, and modify it
Open FilePath For Input As tFile

FileContent = Input(LOF(tFile), tFile)

Close tFile

LineArray = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)
ReDim CodesArray(0 To 2) As String

For Each sLine In LineArray
    CodesArray = Split(sLine, ",")
    For Each line In CodesArray
        sBar = CodesArray(0)
        sBarcode = "*" & sBar & "*"
    Next
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, sBar, sBarcode)
Next

'Open datasource back up and save the modifications
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = oFSO.GetFile(FilePath)
Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)

ts.Write FileContent
ts.Close
End Function
```